# Magento / Zend_Mail() Sending Mail to Spam

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, http-headers, gmail

Magento is complicated...

So all the mail coming from my Magento install is being sent straight to spam. We believe it's either the SMTP server or the headers being set. I read a few articles on Stack about changing Zend_Mail() headers but none of them were Magento specific so anywhere I put the header it would always error out on me.

Does anybody know where I can go to edit the headers that Magentos Zend_Mail() is using?

Comment: Do other messages sent from your server end up in the spam folder for the email account that puts the Magento emails into spam?  There are a number of reasons aside from PHP mail, or Zend_Mail that can cause messages to go to the junk folder.  Such possibilities are no reverse dns (PTR) entry for your mail server IP, SPF rules being broken, or headers being added by the SMTP server.  It might help if you posted the full source (or at least headers) of the messages going to spam.

Comment: yes, I agree with @drew010 it's not always php mail or Zend_Mail who is responsible for mail being sent to spam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Email should not be ending up in spam out of the box. Depending upon where your server is hosted i.e. if it's a shared IP, and if other websites that share that IP are white/black listed with ISP [feedback loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_loop_%28email%29) - this can affect spam filters. Additionally, the header info can cause these issues as well.

As an indirect/alternative solution is to relay your email through a 3rd party established SMTP server, if you have a low volume of emails you can use Google Apps (500/day), or if you need more email throughput you can use something like http://sendgrid.com.

A great module to accomplish this in magento would be: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aschroder-com-smtp-pro-email-free-and-easy-magento-emailing-for-smtp-gmail-or-google-apps-email.html

[edit] Additionally, setting up postfix or any email server can be rather complicated.  Lastly, smtp relays like sendgrid give you the ability to monitor email opens, bounces, etc. via the control panel or a rather extensive api.  This is very useful for ecommerce websites since sending emails can be a very good way to have repeat customers and so forth.

Yes. magento is very complex but highly extensible system, one of the most interesting open source PHP implementations you can experience.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree that Magento is complicated, and some times there is problem with Magento Zend_Mail. 

I was having similar issue. There is a Wiki post on magento website that might be helpful for you [Spam Free Guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/a_spam_free_guide_to_setting_up_your_mail_server_for_magento) or you can look at this thread at Magento [Spam free mail](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/36392/)

Comment: look at the mail header you are receiving, check if you find something unusual there. if you are using mail function, check that -f is present or better, try sending mail using zend_mail_transport_smtp via some trusted and verified smtp. In my case, when I check mail headers, I found server name was something generic and not the actual mail server.

Comment: see that's just it, for some reason / somwehow it looks like it's setting it's header via an array ['To']['From'] etc. And I can't figure out where it's pulling it from. I was in Abstract.php and SendMail.php but still no luck. Anything I put in to hardcode the header in would error out form submissions entirely.

Comment: have tried sending mail using Google SMTP? I mean, if you look at the @anthony answer, it's quite helpful and it deals with issues of junk mails. sometimes isn't not your code, it's something else.